# Replace Angular template with templateUrl using Components

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using Angular 1.5.7 (component structuring) and would like to have some **loading html** show while the component is being loaded from the server.

The code below does not work as i want it to. I would *like* the **loading html** code shown below to appear UNTIL the templateUrl html (coming from the server) is loaded. Once the server-side html is loaded, then replace the **loading html**.

Is this possible?

```
<div class="card field-loading">
  <div class="card-body">
   <div class="loading-text-3"></div>
   <div class="loading-text-10"></div>
   <div class="loading-text-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**HTML**

```
<text-field ng-show="field.type === 'Text'" 
    presenter="vm" form-name="fieldSettingsModel" 
    sidebar-item="true" design-mode="false" field="field">
</text-field>
```

**JS**

```
angular
.module('app.forms.fields.basic')
.component('textField',
{
    require: {
        'app': '^mainApp'
    },
    bindings: {
            field: '=',
            formName: '@',
            designMode: '<',
            presenter: '=',
            mapTo: '<',
            sidebarItem: '<'
    },
    template:`<div class="card field-loading">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="loading-text-3"></div>
                                    <div class="loading-text-10"></div>
                                    <div class="loading-text-4"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>`,
    templateUrl: ['appSettings', appSettings => ('ng/routeArea/FieldTemplate/Text?v=' + appSettings.version)],
    controller: TextFieldComponent,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the template property on your component (leave the templateUrl).

Then place the html you want to show while loading inside the text-field tags:

```
<text-field ng-show="field.type === 'Text'" 
    presenter="vm" form-name="fieldSettingsModel" 
    sidebar-item="true" design-mode="false" field="field">
    <div class="card field-loading">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="loading-text-3"></div>
            <div class="loading-text-10"></div>
            <div class="loading-text-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</text-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably start with something simple as cake:

```
bindings: {
  templateUrl: '<'
}

<div>
<div ng-if="!vm.loaded">
Loading...
</div>
<div ng-include="vm.templateUrl" onload="vm.loaded = true">
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zKkNHuSiXwqwxp4p4yup?p=preview